# Enabling root user on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, root, ubuntu-18.04, passwd

I’ve bought a bare metal server and I was provided with a non-root user to log in.

I’ve tried enabling the root with `sudo passwd root` and changing the password and after I used `sudo passwd -u root` but I still get invalid username/password when I try logging in.

It never happened to me before and I can’t figure out how to get access to root.

Comment: This would be a question for the Unix Stack Exchange, or SuperUser. Unfortunately it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

By default root user is not enabled in Ubuntu.
To Enable root user you should first login by root user and set a password in terminal for root user.

user@computerName:`$ sudo bash

[sudo] password for user: Enter you current user password

root@computerName:/home/user# passwd

New password: Enter your root new password

Now every time you open terminal, type su command to login as root user:

user@computerName:`$ su root

Password: Enter root user password

root@computerName:/home/user# passwd

Answer (score 0):

- write :
  sudo su
  it will ask for your password type it and then you will be working as a root, pay attenti

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).